# Click to Text SMS message and image attachment HTML

Tags: html, sms

Can someone help with adding a image to a post when using Click to Text. Here is the code i have below and I have added an image with the desired results.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2></h2>
<a href="sms:2137322433;?&img src= pic_trulli.jpg;?&body=Good Night, Here's a story to help you get a good nights rest. https://deferred.onelink.me/yU12/psalm4!"; >Click to Send</a>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]